# Django model doesn't save only after query

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I've been working on Django for a while and now I came across this strange problem.

I'm adding a rating feature on a streaming website, for which I wrote a view that is called through a url:

```
url(r'^channel/rate/(?P<stream_id>[\d]*)/(?P<rate>[\d]*)/?$', 'eros.streaming.views.view_rate_channel', 
   name='view_rate_channel'),

def view_rate_channel(request,stream_id,rate):
    if(stream_id and rate and request.user.is_authenticated()):
        stream= Stream.objects.get(id=stream_id)
        if stream not in request.user.channel.rated_streams.all():
            if stream.channel.user != request.user:
                channel=Channel.objects.get(stream=stream)
                channel.rating= channel.rating+int(rate)    
                print("channel rating:   "+str(channel.rating))
                #this prints fine in any case
                channel.n_voters = channel.n_voters +1
                channel.save()
                stream.rating= stream.rating+int(rate)
                stream.n_voters= stream.n_voters+1
                stream.save()    
                request.user.channel.rated_streams.add(stream)
                request.user.channel.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/channel/'+str(stream.channel.id)+'/')  
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/channel/'+str(stream.channel.id)+'/')
```

When I check on the database, the changes I made on the Channel object after channel.save() are not saved, only the changes on the Stream object which I found weird.

So after doing some debugging I decided to comment this if, which I use so users can't rate a stream more than once:

```
        ##if stream not in request.user.channel.rated_streams.all():
```

And now the channel.save() is working!, the bad thing is that I can't let users to rate a stream more than once.

Heres a simplified version of the models:

```
class Channel(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    rating = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    n_voters = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    rated_streams = models.ManyToManyField('Stream', related_name="rated_streams")
    description = models.TextField(default="")

class Stream(models.Model):
    ## I think that maybe this relation is what is causing me trouble (?):
    channel = models.ForeignKey(Channel)
    rating = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    n_voters = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Is there any bad practice or bad query that I'm doing that is making this happen? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: While `if stream` condition is uncommented, changes in the `Channel` object are not getting saved. Is that the issue?

Comment: How is `Channel.objects.get(stream=stream)` is working? There is no `stream` column is your `Channel` model.

Comment: Also, did you verified that `channel` and `request.user.channel` are the same objects?

Comment: About your second comment, That's an interesting thing, because the relation is modeled with a foreign key (one to many) on the stream, there's no field streams on channel. So I tried getting the channel passing the stream as an argument and it returned it, but that was a silly way to call it because I could do it just like channel=stream.channel. I did that and know its working! It's kind of a weird behavior. Thanks a lot tough!

Comment: Sure mate! you mean in the answer below?

Comment: Yes. I will update the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `channel = stream.channel` instead of `channel = Channel.objects.get(stream=stream)` fixed this.

Comment: This would allow the other lines to execute, for example channel.rating= channel.rating+int(rate), which only should happen if the user has not rated the stream yet.

Comment: A channel has many streams, each time a user rates a stream it also rates the channel, but a stream should only be rated once. A user can rate many of the streams of a channel.

Comment: If requested `stream` is already rated by user, should we change `channel` rate (skipping change in stream) or not?

Comment: if the stream is already rated by the user the channel rate is not changed, it only changes when a new stream is going to be rated.